# Infinite loop created for Inverse trig functions

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I have made a class for Complex numbers with various methods, but I am having a problem with the `asin` and `acos` methods. It creates an infinite loop for some reason. Also [here](https://github.com/java-coding-prodigy/Math_stuff2/blob/master/src/io/github/javacodingprodigy/mathstuff2/Complex.java) is the link to the class on github.com

````
package io.github.javacodingprodigy.mathstuff2;
import java.lang.*;
import static io.github.javacodingprodigy.mathstuff2.numberstuff.Approx.approx;
public class Complex {
    private double realPart;
    private double imagPart;
    public static Complex ONE = realValueOf(1);
    public static Complex ZERO = realValueOf(0);
    public static Complex NEGATIVE_ONE = realValueOf(-1);
    public static Complex I = imagValueOf(1);
    public static Complex NEGATIVE_I = imagValueOf(-1);

    public Complex(double real, double imag) {
        realPart = real;
        imagPart = imag;
    }
    Complex(Complex x) {
        realPart = x.getRealPart();
        imagPart = x.getImagPart();
    }
    public double getImagPart() {
        return imagPart;
    }
    public void setImagPart(final double imagPart) {
        this.imagPart = imagPart;
    }
    public double getRealPart() {
        return realPart;
    }
    public void setRealPart(final double realPart) {
        this.realPart = realPart;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex z = new Complex(-1, 0);
        System.out.println(acos(z).toString());
    }
    public String toString() {
        return (this.realPart == 0 ? "" : this.realPart + " ") + (this.imagPart == 0 ? "" :
                Math.abs(imagPart) != 1 ? (String.format("%+f", this.imagPart) + "i") :
                        (imagPart == -1 ? " - i" : " + i")) + (this.imagPart == 0 && this.realPart == 0 ? "0" : "");
    }
    public Complex add(Complex cd) {
        return new Complex(this.getRealPart() + cd.getRealPart(), this.getImagPart() + cd.getImagPart());
    }
    public Complex subtract(Complex cd) {
        Complex x = new Complex(-cd.getRealPart(), -cd.getImagPart());
        return this.add(x);
    }
    public Complex multiply(Complex rs) {
        return new Complex(this.realPart * rs.realPart - this.imagPart * rs.imagPart,
                this.realPart * rs.imagPart + this.imagPart * rs.realPart);
    }
    public Complex divide(Complex rs) {
        double realSol = (this.realPart * rs.realPart + this.imagPart * rs.imagPart) / (rs.realPart * rs.realPart
                + rs.imagPart * rs.imagPart);
        double imagSol = (this.imagPart * rs.realPart - this.realPart * rs.imagPart) / (rs.realPart * rs.imagPart
                + rs.imagPart * rs.imagPart);
        return new Complex(realSol, imagSol);
    }

    public static Complex negate(Complex z) {
        return NEGATIVE_ONE.multiply(z);
    }

    public static Complex reciprocate(Complex z) {
        return ONE.divide(z);
    }

    public Complex mod(Complex ab) {
        return this.add(ab.multiply(ceil(negate(this.divide(ab)))));
    }
    public double getAbs() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.realPart * this.realPart + this.imagPart * this.imagPart);
    }
    public double getAngle() {
        return Math.atan2(this.imagPart, this.realPart);
    }
    public static Complex realValueOf(double z) {
        return new Complex(z, 0);
    }
    public static Complex imagValueOf(double z) {
        return new Complex(0, z);
    }
    public Complex convertFromPolar(double radius, double theta) {
        return new Complex(radius * Math.cos(theta), radius * Math.sin(theta));
    }
    public boolean equals(Complex ab) {
        return approx(this.realPart - ab.realPart) == 0 && approx(this.imagPart - ab.imagPart) == 0;
    }
    public Complex root(double r) {
        double rootAngle = this.getAngle() / r;
        double rootRad = Math.pow(this.getAbs(), 1.0 / r);
        return approx(new Complex(rootRad * Math.cos(rootAngle), rootRad * Math.sin(rootAngle)));
    }
    public Complex sqrt(Complex ab) {
        return ab.root(2);
    }
    public Complex cbrt(Complex ab) {
        return ab.root(3);
    }
    public Complex pow(int k) {
        Complex ans = new Complex(this);
        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            ans = ans.multiply(this);
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public Complex[] rootsOf1(int n) {
        Complex[] roots = new Complex[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
            roots[i] = approx(new Complex(Math.cos(2 * i * Math.PI / n), Math.sin(2 * i * Math.PI / n)));
        }
        return roots;
    }
    public static Complex sin(Complex ab) {
        return approx(new Complex(Math.sin(ab.realPart) * Math.cosh(ab.imagPart),
                Math.cos(ab.realPart) * Math.sinh(ab.imagPart)));
    }
    public static Complex cos(Complex ab) {
        return approx(new Complex(Math.cos(ab.realPart) * Math.cosh(ab.imagPart),
                -Math.sin(ab.realPart) * Math.sinh(ab.imagPart)));
    }
    public static Complex tan(Complex ab) {
        return approx(sin(ab).divide(cos(ab)));
    }
    public static Complex csc(Complex ab) {
        return approx(reciprocate(cos(ab)));
    }
    public static Complex sec(Complex ab) {
        return approx(reciprocate(sin(ab)));
    }
    public static Complex cot(Complex ab) {
        return approx(reciprocate(tan(ab)));
    }
    public static Complex sinh(Complex ab) {
        return approx(new Complex(Math.sinh(ab.realPart) * Math.cos(ab.imagPart),
                Math.cosh(ab.realPart) * Math.sin(ab.imagPart)));
    }
    public static Complex cosh(Complex ab) {
        return approx(new Complex(Math.cosh(ab.realPart) * Math.cos(ab.imagPart),
                Math.sinh(ab.realPart) * Math.sin(ab.imagPart)));
    }
    public static Complex tanh(Complex ab) {
        return approx(sinh(ab).divide(cosh(ab)));
    }
    public static Complex asin(Complex x) {
        Complex b = new Complex(x);
        while (!(approx(sin(b)).equals(x))) {
            b = (b.subtract(sin(b).subtract(x)))
                    .divide(csc(b));
        }
        return b;
    }
    public static Complex acos(Complex x) {
        Complex b = new Complex(x);
        while (!approx(cos(b)).equals(x)) {
            b = b.subtract(cos(b).subtract(x))
                    .divide(negate(sin(b)));
        }
        return b;
    }
    public static Complex floor(Complex ab) {
        return new Complex(Math.floor(ab.realPart), Math.floor(ab.imagPart));
    }
    public static Complex ceil(Complex ab) {
        return new Complex(Math.ceil(ab.realPart), Math.ceil(ab.imagPart));
    }
    public static Complex round(Complex ab) {
        return new Complex(Math.round(ab.realPart), Math.round(ab.imagPart));
    }
    public static Complex sgn(Complex ab){ return  ab.equals(ZERO) ? ZERO : new Complex(Math.cos(ab.getAngle()) , Math.sin(ab.getAngle()));}
}```
Edit: I figured it out what the error was, in `Complex.divide` the imagPart was being returned as NaN, which ruined everything. So I added a check for that which is not included here
````

Comment: There is a lot of code to go through, and this may make your question unattractive to other members of the community, please write a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on that while loop and stepping through your iterations. I wouldn't be surprised if that "equals" condition is never met (or if your calculated value starts oscillating due to lack of precision). It would be helpful to also share the implementation of `approx` that you've imported statically.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas 
```public static Complex approx(Complex z){
        return new Complex(approx(z.getRealPart()), approx(z.getImagPart()));
    }```

Comment: And `approx(double x)` ? seriously this would be a lot easier to help you with if you only included the relevant code from your Complex class, and also all of the relevant code from this other utility class....

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I will keep that in mind next time I ask a question, so anyway here is the code for `approx(double)` ```public static double approx(double a) {
        double epsilon = 0.00000001;
        if (Math.abs(a - Math.round(1000.0 * a) / 1000.0) <= epsilon)
            return Math.round(1000.0 * a) / 1000.0;
        else
            return a;
    }```